# grid-template-columns doesn't exist in notepad++?

Tags: css, notepad++

Trying to make a grid,

```
    .wrapper { 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 48% 52%;
}
```

The issue is that when I type this, display works, but grid-template-elements doesn't go bold, it's as if it doesn't exist? I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

here is an image: [Doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOmMN.png)

Comment: how do I make it work? I tried it but it didn't create any visible grids.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Settings' > 'Style Configurator'

Choose 'Language > CSS', 'IDENTIFIER' then add all your grid properties in user-defined keywords box, separating them with a space.

[image]